# PHP mail() not working in MAMP PRO

Tags: php, email, server, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm using `MAMP PRO 4.2 (9213)` on `MacOS Sierra` with `PHP 7.1.8`.

In the postfix section I filled `my_domain.com` in `domain name for outgoing messages` and I checked `take postfix in GroupStart`.

Calling that short snippet (that works on another server) I'm getting no e-mail (`test@example.com` is placeholder for my real own e-mail):

```
<?php
$to = "test@example.com";
$subject = "Test";
$mail = "Hello, this is a test!";
mail($to,$subject,$mail);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make PHP mail() work?

Comment: The mail function is disabled in MAMP Pro. You will need to look in to using SMTP. Google using a gmail account as a SMTP mail relay.

Comment: Not code-related. Mail-server configuration is entirely off-topic.

Comment: I found the solution: I, of course, have to use smarthost. After checking the smarthost checkbox and filling mail server domain, username and password it worked.

Answer (score -1):

MAMP Pro disables the mail function.

The mail function is pretty terrible for a whole host of reasons, not least of which is that the emails it sends are often regarded as spam by commercial email service providers.

You should consider using an email service like mailjet (which offers 6,000 free emails a month) or sendGrid to send your emails.

Comment: I found the solution: I, of course, have to use smarthost. After checking the smarthost checkbox and filling mail server domain, username and password it worked.